# Как реализовать такую смену валюты на WP?

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. Есть 30 пунктов где указано цена. Это не товары, и не интернет магазин, просто указывается цена для ознакомления.

На сайте предусмотрено смена валюты. Базовая валюта будет доллар и будет еще несколько валют, вплоть до 25. Решили сделать следующий функционал, в админ панели указывается цена лишь в доллары. Так же что бы не грузить API курса валют, будут написаны из админ панели собственные курсы валют, и относительно них через простое математическая операцию будут перерасчет на другую валюту.

Вопрос в следующим, как лучше всего реализовать? Выбор валют - простой список. Так же требуется сохранить значения в куки пользователя максимально долго , насколько это возможно.

Подумал сделать таким образом, что бы при клике на выборе валют, к URL добавлялся параметр `site.ru?valutee=euro`

И уже исходя из этого делать брать базовую цену в доллары, курс доллара к евро , и написать цену.

Но меня беспокоит одна вещь. Правильно ли будет делать столько проверок, потому что валют может быть около 25. И надо будет писать для каждой , Если валюта евро, выведи такую цену, если валюта рубли выведи такую цену, если валюта фунт стерлинг выведи эту. Немного напрягается такой подход, но других вариантов я тут не вижу . Может есть более отличный способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой пример Вам собрал, он использует не куки а localStorage:

```js
function recalc() {
  let curr = currency.options[currency.selectedIndex].text;
  let rate = currency.value;
  document.querySelectorAll('.price').forEach(el => 
    el.textContent = (el.dataset.price / rate).toFixed(2) + " " + curr)
  localStorage.setItem("currency", curr)
}

try { // localStorage не работает в сниппетах на stackoverflow
  let curr = localStorage.getItem("currency")
  currency.selectedIndex = [...currency.options].findIndex(o => o.text === curr);
} catch (e) {}

recalc()
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div>apples</div>
<div class=price data-price=150></div><br>
<div>oranges</div>
<div class=price data-price=200></div><br>
<div>grapes</div>
<div class=price data-price=300></div><br>

<select id=currency onchange=recalc()>
  <option value=1>rub</option>
  <option value=65.34>usd</option>
  <option value=71.94>eur</option>
</select>
```

Comment: чуть позже заверну в сниппет, с телефона это сделать крайне сложно

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за отличную идею